# draw map scale in geopandas

Tags: scale, geopandas, matplotlib-basemap

Is there a geopandas version of [basemap's `m.drawmapscale`](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawmapscale) function? 
If not, can I somehow utilize basemap's `drawmapscale` function within geopandas?

Comment: Geopandas uses cartopy for map plotting, here is a link to the map scale plotting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333870/how-can-i-show-a-km-ruler-on-a-cartopy-matplotlib-plot